# Custom css style for gwt button

Tags: css, gwt, button

I have the following code

```
Button orderButton = new Button("");
orderButton.setStyleName("OrderButton");
orderButton.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("marginTop", "35px");
```

The CSS looks like this

```
.OrderButton { 
      width:208px;
      height:43px; 
      background-image:url('graphics/OrderButton.jpg');border:0;margin:auto; 
}

.OrderButton-down { 
      width:208px;
      height:43px; 
      background-image:url('graphics/OrderButton_down.jpg');border:0;margin:auto; 
}
```

But clicking on the button does not change anything. The style remains the same "OrderButton" and "OrderButton-down" is ignored.

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the usual css tags active and hover?

> ".OrderButton-down" would then look like this ".OrderButton:active"
>   This way you can also use the :hover tag

Answer (score 0):

It is the ToggleButton's that have the .gwt-ToggleButton-down style.  For a normal button do as Philipp suggested.